# How do I connect a random array with an array that is related by subject topic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a little app to randomly pick a park in Disney world for me to go to, once I am at that park I then want to press the button-
"What should I ride?" for it to tell me what ride to go on in that part of the park it picked for me.

Like if it said

"Go to Animal Kingdom" then when I press the 
"What shall I ride?"

I want it to say "Expedition Everest".
But it picks a park randomly so I'm not sure how to link another array that would be random but match in the sense the park and ride are in the same part of the park.

Code Sample:

```
public void LoadNextScene()
{
    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);
}

public void LoadStartScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}

public void OnPressPap()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}

public void OnPressRides()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
```

above is my simple scene loader once a button is pressed.

```
{
    public string[] ParkNameArray;
    public string ParkName;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ParkNameText;    
    private void Start()
    {
        ParkName = ParkNameArray[Random.Range(0, ParkNameArray.Length)];
        ParkNameText.text = ParkName.ToString();
    }    
}
```

Above are my array and the random range which I use in unity to edit.

I will add some images below of what my ugly UI looks like with also the array list of the parks.

[Array list in unity (Parks only atm)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NADyu.png)

[Pick a ride](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zTfj.png)

This image below is where I want to press The "what to ride?" button and it be related with the park that just got picked.

[Ride picked randomly with random fact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXYbz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Objects

This is why [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is a thing.

Instead of creating two arrays and trying to figure out who you link one array to another, you collapse those arrays into *objects* and create a single array of *those.*

For example, each park (the object) contains rides (an array). There are multiple (an array) of parks.

```
public class Park {
    public string parkName;
    public Ride[] listOfRides; //Ride is similarly defined like Park is
}
```

And then your other code:

```
{
    public Park[] ParksArray;
    //...
}
```

Now all you need is to randomly select a park, get its rides, and randomly select a ride from that list:

```
int randPark = Random.Range(0, ParksArray.Length);
Ride[] availableRides = ParksArray[randPark].listOfRides;
int randRide = Random.Range(0, availableRides.Length);
Debug.Log(ParksArray[randPark].name + ":" + availableRides[randRide].name);
```

Comment: This in combination with scriptableobjects in unity is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much! this is really helpful.

Comment: @Immorality I (personally) haven't figured out how to work Scriptable Objects into my architecting mindspace. I understand what they *are* but I haven't figured out what problem they actually *solve.*

Answer (score 1):

You can store your array in an scriptable object that you will assign to you scripts. 
More info [here](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects)